# Get value from cell next to another cell

Tags: google-sheets

I've got two sheets.

**SHEET ONE**

```
Product    | Grams    | Kcal
Food       | 23       | ?
Food2      | 55       | ?
```

**SHEET TWO**

```
Product    | Kcal
Food       | 104
Food2      | 33
```

How can I in Sheet One find the cell next to the food I entered.
Ex. When I enter "Food2", I want it to automatically get the Kcal value from the Food list in my Sheet Two.

So Food2's Kcal cell should be like 33*55

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in cell C2 of your Sheet1:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,B2:B*VLOOKUP(A2:A,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)))`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, but I found another solution, thanks.